# combating mission which approaches innocent Jews

Tags: discussion

I see recently a great number of posts about Christianity: pseudo-innocent questions that seem to ask about the legitimacy of some missionary religious sect or of יש"ו. I feel that Mi Yodeya is too friendly and we are duty-bound to protect people who are frail. Why moderators do not clean up a little more? 
See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71006/who-is-the-prophet-yehoshua-the-nazarene-in-judaism), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71002/is-a-conversion-through-jerusalem-council-valid), <del>[here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70085/according-to-judaism-how-is-gods-promise-to-bless-all-nations-through-abraham#comment201485_70085)</del> for examples.
and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/why-dont-jews-think-jesus-is-the-messiah)

Comment: This question would be stronger and more answerable if you'd [edit] in some specific examples of posts that fit this category along with details of what actions you think need to be taken toward them and why.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I tried to remember and linked few examples

Comment: thanks. Like I said, details about what you think mods ought to do in these cases would be valuable.

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite this in better English and am stuck on "Why moderators do not clean up a little more". Do you mean "Why don't moderators clean up a little more?!" as a proposal (they should!) or "Why do moderators not clean up a little more?" as a question (please explain why)?

Comment: @msh210 Yes I think that the moderators have a great responosability and duty to protect Jewish people

Comment: @msh210 "which", "witch one": I am confused have you a link to explain

Comment: http://grammarist.com/homophones/which-vs-witch/

Comment: @msh210 You make Mitsva מכשפה לא תחיה!

Comment: @Kouty I strongly believe that none of the questions you linked involves proselytizing or is otherwise objectionable. I'm not sure what our obligation is to keep proselyters off the site but we indeed have an obligation to make darchei shalom and kiddush Hashem in the view of the nations--and to act as fair, reasonable, non-parochial human beings. In light of the last point especially, I think the numerous downvotes on these (generally good) questions are not merited

Comment: @SAH I agree that my examples are not wholly adequate, I agree too with the Kidush Hashem.  But the example of the Jeru C. makes my blood boil, because in Israel it is the classical baiting for frail people. They make great damages.

Answer (score 9):

Posts (questions or answers) that exist only to proselytize other religions are not welcome here, and when the moderators become aware of them we delete them.  The community can help with flags.  If a post is offensive or spam be sure to use the correct flag; doing so can expedite removal.

The problem comes in posts that aren't that blatant, ones that might be asked with ulterior motives or might be asked out of ignorance.  The last of your three examples, for example, is asked respectfully and from an admitted lack of knowledge by someone who declares his religious perspective up front; that seems wholly unobjectionable to me.  Your other examples are less clear in this regard but do not, in my opinion, cross this line.  *Dan l'chaf zichut* means we should give the benefit of the doubt, so we don't remove borderline posts unilaterally.  The site is open to everybody, including non-Jews who sometimes lack basic knowledge.  We should distinguish between the one who does not know how to ask and the one who posts with bad intent.

This doesn't mean we can't respond to poor posts in other ways, though.  If a post is unclear or shows no research, you might want to downvote it.  If a question is unclear or off-topic or opinion-based or too broad, you can vote (or flag) to close it.  You can leave comments requesting clarification or suggesting improvements, and if a poster seems to be sincere but misguided I encourage you to give him a hand.

Please help us to be as open as possible while shutting down the trolls and missionaries.  There are a lot of people out there, gentiles *and* Jews, who have some basic misunderstandings and could benefit from coming here for answers.  Let's try not to shut them out.

Comment: I never said to shut out anybody. It's clear! +1 for the chaf zchout. I greatly appreciate your prose.

Comment: @kouty it was not my intent to put words in your mouth.  I'm sorry if you thought I was.

Comment: All is good I was not cynic. I really said that it is beautiful to be able to kep these posts lechaf zechut. I appreciate it really. I am sure.

Answer (score 4):

I think that posting sources from other religions shouldn't be accepted, as this is a site about Judaism and this should be about Judaism only. If they want to ask if we believe in oisoi ho'ish, that's fine because it's asking about Judaism, but to bring a Christian translation of the Torah and based on that ask why we don't hold of him would be inter-religious discussion which I don't think should be on this site.
It would seem more appropriate to be in the Christian site as they hold that Judaism was an authentic religion and a precursor to their religion.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to questions like these, it is important to remember that Mi Yodeya is *not* a Jewish site. Yes, we are a site that is *about* Judaism. Yes, most of our users are Jewish. But censoring opinions that is not in accordance with Judaism (as long as they are not *provably wrong* and as long as they are not *offensive* and as long as they are not *off topic*), is not the moderators' responsibility, nor should anybody do that.

Comment: This would make more sense about answers I think than questions.

Comment: not a Jewish site --> OK, all is open. 100% right.
But a question witch concern not Judaism even if it is a Jewish question is not on topic
An other point is to detect spam. Missionary is spam, nothing else.

Comment: @Daniel I think a second time. you say right and beautyful things, are "censoring" the point of my question, and  you falsely attribute to me some opinion and answer to this. Nothing in my post says that m.y. is a Jewish royalty. My topic is the awareness about propaganda and disguised missionarism. I you think that it is prohibited in a non-Jewish site to spoke on illegal and threatening advertising.

Comment: @kouty agreed. Posts that are clearly arguments against Judaism don't have any place here. But the questions that you linked are not that. They show poor research effort, but they are legitimately questions about Judaism

Comment: @DoubleAA my answer has the caveat that it only applies to questions that aren't off-topic. I think the only difference between questions and answers is that questions are more likely to be off-topic.

Comment: @Daniel I agree that the posts  are not the best examples of propaganda. But a least, in  the post of Jer. Con. it is impossible to leave this withoutd caution against an this missionary organization. י"ש

Comment: @kouty my use of the term "censorship" should not be taken to have an automatically negative connotation. Removal of spam is also censorship, though an important aspect of site maintenance.